# Creating taxonomy diagrams that could include long text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am now writing a survey paper and I would like to create a taxonomy that organizes the previous works. I checked out the https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/ but the provided templates do not seem to be applicable to my case: I need to put some (sometimes) long comments at the terminal nodes.

I saw two examples that might be relevant (they are taken from [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.13586.pdf) and [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.01852.pdf)) but not sure if they come from some template I am not aware of.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Mr Robot, this question is too long to ask for human's help ^^

Comment: I do not expect someone could typeset entire diagram. Just wondering if there is some similar templates I was not aware of.

Comment: maybe this ? `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw=#1,fill=#1!30,rounded corners}}
\path
(0,0) node[box=violet] (A) {box A}
(2,0) node[box=blue] (B) {box B}
(2,1) node[box=cyan] (C) {box C}
;
\draw (A)|-(C);
\draw[->] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`